# How to match a category with sentence using dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text, categorization

I have the following sentences and dict :

```
dictio = {'col1': ['smell', 'scent'], 'col2': ['color', 'red','blue'],'col3':['long','small']}

Sentence = ["The color of pants is blue and red","The tshirt smell very good", "She is a tall person", 
"The monkey is playing"]
```

I want to match a sentence with its category :

```
dic_keys = dictio.keys()
resultat = []
for key_dics in dic_keys:
    for values in dictio[key_dics]:
        for sent in Sentence:
            if values in sent.lower().split():
                resultat.append(key_dics)
```

I get the following result :

`['col1', 'col2', 'col2', 'col3']`

But I need this results :

`['col2', 'col1', 'col3', 'KO']`

When I complete my for loop with an else condition.I have a strange result.

I need your help for resolving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues in your question as well as code.

Your excepted results is wrong - it only has 4 values when it needs 5 - and also, the col3 should have `smell` and not `small` to get the results you need.

Your for loops can be optimized.

```
dictio = {'col1': ['smell', 'scent'], 'col2': ['color', 'red','blue'],'col3':['long','smell']}

Sentence = ["The color of pants is blue and red","The tshirt smell very good", "She is a tall person", "The monkey is playing"]

res = []
flag = True

for sent in Sentence:
  for k, v in dictio.items():
    if [x for x in v if x in sent.split()]:
      res.append(k)
      flag = False
  if flag:
    res.append("KO")
  flag = True

print(res)
# ['col2', 'col1', 'col3', 'KO', 'KO']
```